# GET and POST issue in laravel chat using Pusher and Vue.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, pusher

I have a problem following this tutorial to implement a simple chat in Laravel using Pusher and Vue.js: [link tutorial](http://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/).

First of all my route in the navbar is this one:

> http://localhost/youChat/public/

My web.php file contents the following routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'TweetController@index');
Route::get('tweets', 'TweetController@showTweets')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('tweets', 'TweetController@sentTweet')->middleware('auth');
```

My app.js file in assets/js where I make the request is this one:

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
    tweets: []
},
created() {
    this.showTweets();
    Echo.private('chat')
        .listen('TweetSentEvent', (e) => {
        this.tweets.push({
            tweet: e.tweet.tweet,
            user: e.user
 });
 });
 },
methods: {
    showTweets() {
        axios.get('/tweets').then(response => {
            this.tweets = response.data;
        });
    },
     addTweet(tweet) {
        this.tweets.push(tweet);

        axios.post('/tweets', qs.stringify(tweet)).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
});
```

As you can see I send the request with Axios.

Everything seems looks fine but the GET and POST request are not working. The error in the console inspector shows this:

> GET http://localhost/tweets 404 (Not Found)
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
>      at createError (app.js:13931)
>      at settle (app.js:35401)
>      at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:13805)
>
> GET https://stats.pusher.com/timeline/v2/jsonp/1session=Njg3NjQyNDY5NT....MjY1fV0%3D 0 ()
>   POST http://localhost/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)

And when I try to make a POST:

> POST http://localhost/tweets 404 (Not Found)

The get/post should go to this direction:

> http://localhost/youChat/public/tweets

but I don't know what's happening. Any suggestion? I'm desperated :D. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using an absolute path.

So either you can store the Base url in a variable or you can use relative path

here is an example.

```
methods: {
    showTweets() {
        axios.get('tweets').then(response => {
            this.tweets = response.data;
        });
    },
     addTweet(tweet) {
        this.tweets.push(tweet);

        axios.post('tweets', qs.stringify(tweet)).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

Remove the `/` before the URL or

save a

`const URL = '{{url('/')}}'`

```
methods: {
    showTweets() {
        axios.get(URL + '/tweets').then(response => {
            this.tweets = response.data;
        });
    },
     addTweet(tweet) {
        this.tweets.push(tweet);

        axios.post(URL + '/tweets', qs.stringify(tweet)).then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Worked perfectly :D thank you very much mate! Removing the dash solved the problem.